# Why echo \\\\ shows \

Tags: shell, backslash

Could anyone explain how backslashes function in these cases to me?

I understand if you put 1 \ it goes to next line (escapes \n). If you put 2 \ , then it shows one backslash, because the other one is escaped.

What i don't understand is why inputing 4 backslashes only gives you back 1 and not 2 ? Or why inputing 8 backslashes only gives you 2 and not 4? Thanks!

```
sh-3.2$ echo \\
\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\
\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\\\
\\
sh-3.2$ echo \\\\\\\\
\\
```

Comment: Looks strange and doesn't behave like that on my shell...I guess it's something specific to older `sh`?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior does not match the standard `echo` builtin. Your `echo` command is probably aliased to `echo -e` which interprets escaped sequences:

- With `echo \\\\`, the shell considers two consecutive \ to be only one single \ character (the first one escaping the second one) and it calls `echo` with the string `\\` as a parameter. The string `\\` is printed normally.
- With `echo -e \\\\`, the shell does the same job but then `echo` searches its parameter (`\\`) for escaped characters which are interpreted again. So, two consecutive `\` make only one `\` displayed. That's why the string `\` is printed.

You can check that your `echo` is aliased with the `type` builtin:

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ alias echo='echo -e'
$ type echo
echo is aliased to `echo -e'
```

You can force the use of the `echo` builtin in two ways:

```
$ builtin echo \\\\
\\
$ \echo \\\\
\\
```

Comment: I tried running the ```builtin echo \\\\``` and ```\echo \\\\``` on different shells zsh and sh and they still return ```\```. Both of the shells are up to date.